# How to access local url from wifi network when mobile data is turned on?

Tags: android, networking, mobile, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I am not able to access my local network server url when my internet is on.
Current scenario of my android mobile phone:-
Wifi - on (with no internet)
Internet - on

I am not able to access my local server url 192.168.42.1:4456

Comment: It's not a programming issue. The issue is the smartphone has both option and will choose the LTE connection to get on the internet. Disabling your LTE will allow you to access your local server.

Comment: I know its hardware specific but some application lke speedify allow you to do that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic. You may be able to get help on https://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to do port forwarding from your router. Every router has a different interface but basics are same.
Go to port forwarding,  in the incoming port select a port number e.g. 10456 and in target use the ip address and port number of the local machine.

Comment: our wifi has no internet connection so this will not be the case

Comment: You do not need internet connection for port forwarding. It is a feature of the router.